# Dataframe Index value

Tags: dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event1':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre', 'Comedy'], 
                    'Event2':[Poetry, Music, Dance, Theater]})

I need to create a new column called 'Val' that has the index of the element from Event 2 as it occurs in Event1.  For example Val would be 
'Val':[1,0,NaN,2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you can do:

> **Solution 1**

```
import numpy as np

df['val'] = df['Event2'].apply(lambda x: np.where(x == df['Event1'])[0][0]) 

print(df)

    Event1   Event2  val
0    Music   Poetry    1
1   Poetry    Music    0
2  Theatre   Comedy    3
3   Comedy  Theatre    2
```

> **Solution 2**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event1':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theater', 'Comedy'], 'Event2':['Poetry', 'Music', 'Dance', 'Theater']})

df['val'] = (df['Event2']
                 .apply(lambda x: np.argwhere(x == df['Event1']))
                 .apply(lambda x: x[0][0] if len(x)>0 else x)
                )
df['val'] = pd.to_numeric(df['val'], errors='coerce')

print(df)

    Event1   Event2  val
0    Music   Poetry  1.0
1   Poetry    Music  0.0
2  Theater    Dance  NaN
3   Comedy  Theater  2.0
```

Comment: I get an index error with index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: My problem is that I have elements in Event2 that are not in Event1.  How do I correct for that ??

Comment: @NandaNathan not sure why you get the error, may be your data has missing values. can you check?

Comment: can you update the example with a case where the solution fails? I will be happy to modify it accordingly

Comment: Thanks YOLO...Here is the updated version...df = pd.DataFrame({'Event1':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre', 'Comedy'], 'Event2':[Poetry, Music, Dance, Theater]})

I need to create a new column called 'Val' that has the index of the element from Event 2 as it occurs in Event1. For example Val would be 'Val':[1,0,NaN,2].

Comment: Beautiful and elegant YOLO. Works great and is awesome.  Thanks man.